# two click events works at same time

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In an Angular form. I have two elements one button and one input element. button has (click) function and input has (keydown.enter) function. although they are implemented seperately. when i click enter in the input field, the click function of the button also applies. what can be the problem and how can i seperate those two events without coliding eachother. please guide me.

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jtnzwn)

HTML

```
form [formGroup] = "testform">
<div class="col-1 col-md-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button nbButton (click)=test1()>test1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 d-flex justify-content-center ">
                <input class='pl-2' nbInput fieldSize="Large" fullWidth type='search'
                       placeholder="search"
                       (keydown.enter)="search($event)">
              </div>
</form>
```

TS

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  testform: FormGroup;
  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder,){}
   ngOnInit(): void {
this.testform = this.fb.group([]);
   }
   test1(){
console.log('testtest');
   }
   search(event:any){
console.log(event.target.value);
   }
}
```

Comment: maybe because your button is of `type="submit"` (default) and when you hit enter in your input field it also submits the form, triggering the submit button?

Comment: Try to use `event.stopPropagation()` inside search function.